# Replacing object values with animations

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, animation

I have a large array of objects. All objects are the same and have the following structure.

`{ title: 'Text', value: 'Text'}`

I loop through the array with a `map`, but don't want to draw all the objects, but only two of them. The rest should replace them using animation. I have already spent a lot of time, but I can’t come up with a strategy for replacing objects. For example:

```
const myLargeArray = [ 
                      {title: 'first', value: '1'},
                      {title: 'second', value: '2'},
                      {title: 'third', value: '3'},
                      {title: 'fourth', value: '4'},
                     ]

   {myLargeArray.map((item, index) => {
      return (
        <View key={item + index}>
          <Animated.Text>{`${title}: `}</Animated.Text>
          <Animated.Text>{value}</Animated.Text>
        </View>
      );
    })}
```

In this option, I will draw all four objects, but I need only two to be drawn, and for example, after 1 second, their values changed to the next two objects from the array.

Comment: just use a for loop and loop only 2. creata a function that run a timer every N seconds and start reading from index 2.

Comment: Could you give me an example?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like:

```
const [first, second, ...rest] = largeArray;

<>
  {[first, second].map(({ item }) => (
    <>{/* don't animate */}</>
  ))}
  {rest.map(({ item }) => (
    <>{/* animate */}</>
  ))}
</>;
```

Or to be more generic, use [`#Array.slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice).